# implications of using function/class as a "value" in Javascript Map()

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, typescript, collections, jasmine

I have a class which manages few requests. So requests are set up as a collection. I've done this way to avoid having to write lengthy switch/if else statements.

```
// Manager class
class makeManagerRequests() {
  private list = [];
  private createList(body) {
    this.list.push(body)
  }
  createEmployee(body) {
    this.createlist(body);
  }
  updateManager(body);
  deleteManager(body);
}

// Employee class
class makeEmployeeRequests() {

  private list = [];
  private createList(body) {
    this.list.push(body)
  }
  createEmployee(body) {
    this.createlist(body);
  }
  updateEmployee(body)
  deleteEmployee(body)
}

// Usage in a generic widget
class makeRequests() {

  requestMap = new Map();

  constructor(makeManagerRequests, makeEmployeeRequests) {

  }

  createRequestMap() {
    requestMap.set('createManager', this.makeManagerRequest.createManager.bind(this));
    requestMap.set('updateManager', this.makeManagerRequest.updateManager.bind(this));
    requestMap.set('deleteManager', this.makeManagerRequest.deleteManager.bind(this));
    requestMap.set('createEmployee', this.makeManagerRequest.createEmployee.bind(this));
    requestMap.set('updateEmployee', this.makeManagerRequest.updateEmployee.bind(this));
    requestMap.set('deleteEmployee', this.makeManagerRequest.deleteEmployee.bind(this));
  }

  makeRequest(data) {
    let req = requestMap.get(data.requestType);
    req(data.body)
  }

}
```

This itself works.

First thing I noticed was keyword "this" change scope when using get Map from "service" to the "widget" so that `createlist()` become undefined. BUT if I just do this without bind it works.

```
  // I can test this with mocking the makeManagerRequest
  makeRequest(data) {
    this.makeManagerRequest.updateEmployee(body)        
  }
```

When using map I need `.bind(this)`. Not sure why "this" change? Issue this creates is when I try to test and mock the service and spy on service. I get spy never been called. So I think what happens is bind create new function when creating the map. So I can't spy on

```
spyOn(MockMakeManagerRequest, 'updateEmployee')
```

So I am trying to figure out how does the functions themselves stored in the Map(). I am looking for technical implications this collection and how I can make this work so I can implement tests around this.

This is actually being used with in Angular 2 app. But I don't think it would make much difference as I am trying to figure what happens to/test functions when stored as a value in Map();

Comment: At least related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work, possibly I should have used one of those (probably the second) in a close-as-duplicate vote.

Comment: Yeah, really, if you look past the `Map` aspect, it's a duplicate of that second one. But I'll leave the community wiki answer below in case it's useful.

Answer (score 0):

What's stored in the `Map` is a function reference, nothing more. The `this` problem you're having has nothing to do with `Map` (other than that it uses function references), it's just how functions and `this` work in JavaScript. Let's take a simpler example:

```js
class Example {
  constructor(message) {
    this.message = message;
  }
  method() {
    console.log(this.message);
  }
}
const c = new Example("Hi");
c.method(); // "Hi"
const f = c.method;
f();        // Error: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined
```

When `method` is called, it's *how it's called* that determines what `this` is: If we call it using an expression that gets it from `c`, then `this` during the call to it will have the value `c` has. But if we don't, it usually won't, it'll have some other value.

I realize you were asking why `this` is wrong, not how to solve it, but having explained why it's wrong, here are three options for solving it:

1. `Function#bind` solves that by creating a function that, when called, calls the original with `this` set to a specific value.
2. Another solution is to use arrow functions as wrappers:

   ```
   requestMap.set('createManager', (...args) => this.makeManagerRequest.createManager(...args));
   ```

   Arrow functions *don't* have their `this` set by how they're called, they *close over* `this` just like closing over an in-scope variable. So since we're defining them inside a call to `createRequestMap` where `this` is the object we want to use, arrows close over that `this` and we're good.
3. Another option is to change the call that uses the function reference:

   ```
   makeRequest(data) {
     let req = requestMap.get(data.requestType);
     req.call(this, data.body);
   // --^^^^^^^^^^^^
   }
   ```

   There, we're explicitly saying what we want `this` to be during the call to `req`.

Comment: I was getting confused because `makeRequest(data) {
    this.makeManagerRequest.updateEmployee(body)        
  }` works. BUT `requestMap.get(data.requestType)(body)` didn't work without bind. hence it made me think its something to do with how it's stored within Map.

Comment: I would assume that 3rd option will solve jasmine spy issue too?

Comment: @MonteCristo: I haven't used it, but I'd think so, yes.